# Converting Object to XML Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, soap, web-services

I am looking for a tutorial, description, or something that could point me in the right direction for converting an object to an XML soap request in Cocoa.  Specifically I am using this to hit a .NET webservice.  I do at this point have my code working but it feels like cheating and bad chi.

My XMl request is basically lots of:

```
Request = [Request stringByAppendingString:@"<Name>"];
Request = [Request stringByAppendingString:obj.name];
Request = [Request stringByAppendingString:@"</Name>"];
```

This means my page is very static and not very future proof to say the least.

In .net I would just put a web reference in my project and like magic I can call the web method with actual parameters and it works well.

Is there anything that could help make the above less scary? Reflection maybe?  I am looking for a way to send in an object and to have a mostly magical xml object come out.

Just a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [Constructing XML Tree Structures section](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/ConstructingTrees.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002268-BCIEABEE) of the Event-Driven XML Programming Guide. I'd just add a method to my class called -xmlRepresentation.

There are also myriad SOAP demos for Cocoa a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=cocoa+soap&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) away. [This article](http://www.macresearch.org/interacting-soap-based-web-services-cocoa-part-2) may also help.